# How to force Gallery to open in landscape orientation?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, android-orientation

My app runs in landscape mode.
I have `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` set in AndroidManifest.xml file.
If the screen orientation of the device is locked to portrait mode, then my app still runs in landscape mode. But the gallery activity started from within the app runs in portrait mode.
Is there any way to force gallery activity to always run in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the device is locked to portrait mode, There is no way to achieve this.

Of course you could try to change *the device* orientation to landscape (in your app) so that the gallery runs in landscape but this will cause a confusion to the user.

Comment: My application is already locked to landscape mode. Is there a way to change device orientation setting?